# How to setup libgdx game for different screen sizes?

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx

This is my first time to use LibGDX. I have created my first game on Android based on libGDX. The Textures / Images are scaled differently on different screen sizes that the game is impossible to be played.
I wanted to use mipmap, and create each image with different size in each folder, but android.os.Bundle can't be imported in the Game class, so I can't use R.mipmap..etc.
I have been searching for a solution for two days now. I hope you help me here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a viewport. There are different kinds of viewports you can use to make sure your game looks good on all screen sizes.

links:

[LibGDX wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports)

[Aspect Ratios & Viewports tutorial by Brent Aureli](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7u5B2Oh9r0)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Personally I like to use a FitViewPort. This does however create black bars to make it all look the same but the proportions and coordinates you implemented are the same on every device without extra work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Scene and add Actor. then you can configure for differently sized screens. I had this problem, and this helped me solve it.